# fetch sent emails from gmail imap using nodejs

Tags: node.js, imap, nodemailer, gmail-imap

I'm trying to fetch SENT emails from gmail server using nodemailer through Imap.

the solution below is not working and the result is the INBOX not SENT

```
var imap = new Imap({
        user: request.body.email,
        password: request.body.password,
        host: '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX.Sent',
        port: 993,
        tlsOptions: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
        tls: true
    });
```

Comment: Gmail doesn't name its mailboxes in the way you assume. Issue a `LIST` request and find the proper names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on the next links:

1. [Special-Use Extension of the LIST command](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-extensions#special-use_extension_of_the_list_command)

```
...
* LIST (\HasNoChildren \Sent) "/" "[Gmail]/Sent Mail"
...
```

As you can see `[Gmail]/Sent Mail` is all what you need.

*Remember*, the label name will be changed if your interface language is different to english.

2. And here is an example about how to [Access to Gmail labels: X-GM-LABELS](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-extensions#access_to_gmail_labels_x-gm-labels)

```
...
* 1 FETCH (X-GM-LABELS (\Inbox \Sent Important "Muy Importante"))
...
```