# How Can i receive incoming mails(gmail) to my application server using imap (nodejs)

Tags: gmail, imap, gmail-imap

I would like to read the complete incoming mail using imap. But imap is only notifying me the number of new mails I have received

```
 imap.on('mail', (number) => {
      console.log('got mails', number);
    });
```

Is there any way I can read the incoming mails ?

Any help would be thankful

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if you need further help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Take a look on [Node.js Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs), it will guide you very well.
2. Use [Users.messages: list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) to get mail ids, here is a direct link of [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22me%22%2C%22labelIds%22%3A%5B%22SENT%22%5D%7D)
3. Once you get your **email id list**, you can use [Users.messages: get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get)
4. Take a look on [fetch sent emails from gmail **imap** using **nodejs**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61581925/fetch-sent-emails-from-gmail-imap-using-nodejs/61932461#61932461)

---

Here is a step by step guide how to get your mail inbox:

1. [Enable IMAP](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/fwdandpop)
2. [Enable less secure apps](https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/lesssecureapps?pageId=none)
3. [Install imap package](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap) with `npm install imap`
4. Create **index.js** with the next code:

```js
const Imap = require('imap'), inspect = require('util').inspect;

const myMail = "***@gmail.com";
const myPwd = "***";

let getEmailFromInbox = (mailServer) => {

  mailServer.openBox('INBOX', true, function (err, box) {

    if (err) throw err;

    let f = mailServer.seq.fetch('1:*', {
      bodies: 'HEADER.FIELDS (FROM TO SUBJECT DATE)',
      struct: true
    });

    f.on('message', function (msg, seqno) {
      console.log('Message #%d', seqno);
      let prefix = '(#' + seqno + ') ';

      msg.on('body', function (stream, info) {
        let buffer = '';

        stream.on('data', function (chunk) {
          buffer += chunk.toString('utf8');
        });

        stream.once('end', function () {
          console.log(prefix + 'Parsed header: %s', inspect(Imap.parseHeader(buffer)));
        });

      });

    });

    f.once('error', function (err) {
      console.log('Fetch error: ' + err);
    });

    f.once('end', function () {
      console.log('Done fetching all messages!');
    });

  });

}

let createLabel = (mailServer, labelName) => {
  mailServer.addBox(labelName, (err) => {});
  console.log('message', 'New Label or Box Created');
}

let getMailboxStatusByName = (mailServer, inboxName) => {
  mailServer.status(inboxName, (err, mailbox) => {
    console.log('message', mailbox);
  });
  console.log('message', 'Label or Box Status');
}

let getMailBoxLabels = (mailServer) => {
  mailServer.getBoxes((error, mailbox) => {
    console.log('message', mailbox);
  })
}

let deleteLabel = (mailServer, labelName) => {
  mailServer.delBox(labelName, (error) => {})
  console.log('message', 'Label or Box removed');
}

let mailServer1 = new Imap({
  user: myMail,
  password: myPwd,
  host: 'imap.gmail.com',
  port: 993,
  tls: true,
  tlsOptions: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  },
  authTimeout: 3000
}).once('error', function (err) {
  console.log('Source Server Error:- ', err);
});
mailServer1.once('ready', function () {
  mailServer1.openBox('INBOX', true, function (err, box) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('message', 'server1 ready');
  });

  // mail operation
  //getMailBoxLabels(mailServer1);
  getEmailFromInbox(mailServer1)
  //createLabel(mailServer1, "demo-label1");
  //deleteLabel(mailServer1, "demo-label1");
  //getMailboxStatusByName(mailServer1, "INBOX");
})

mailServer1.connect();
```

5. run `node index.js` and check your mail output

adapt this snippet to your needs

Comment: Hi jeff, thanks for your answer. I am trying to do something like ticket management. If someone sent a mail to support@mydomain.com my server should get notified with details like (from, subject) immediately. So that I can read that email and create a ticket ex- (Zendesk, Freshdesk). One solution I have found for that is using IMAP. Is there any better approach to do that ? I would be thankful to you if you could provide me any help on this